# Is it possible to have Async Socket in Mono for Android using C#?

Tags: c#, tcp, xamarin.android, asyncsocket

I just started developing a sample application for Mono. The main task is to implement a tcp-socket server on the android tablet listening for connections from a client. after connecting the client starts sending real-time data and the android application displays the data on the screen. this is important to implement the server side on the android. I am using Mono for Android / C# . I already have about a week google searching and sample browsing.

My question is: if the Async TCP socket works on the android mono framework or not. because my code works fine when I use it in "windows application" to "windows application" platform. but when I change it to "windows application" to "android" the connection simply disconnects.

I know the question is wage, I know you all expect sample source... If I had a place to put the sample, I would definitely put it!

- I am using Mono for Android Api 12 Emulator
- I already forwarded the TCP port using emulator telnet console 'redir' command
- connection establishes but data does not being received on the server (android side)

any help/sample/guide will be appreciated

Comment: Have you tried it on a device?  I know getting the emulator's networking settings are pretty crazy.  I don't see why using the socket would not work in MonoDroid if it works in Windows.

Comment: Quick not to say that **MonoTouch** is "Mono for iOS" while "Mono for Android" is "Mono for Android". They share quite a lot but they are different products.

Comment: update: thanks guys for the time for reading and commenting. I just found the problem. the only difference between 'windows' version of the server and 'android' version was in the 'message deserialization' namespace. (blabla.mono.net / blabla.windows.net) which has been solved by changing the assemblyname in the  "BindToType" method of DeserializationAppDomainBinder. now message arrives at the server side nice and smooth :) thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to have Async Socket in Android using Mono. there is no specific difference with windows application for this scenario. my problem was actually from de-serializing the message which caused the connection to stop. 
problem solved by adding new DesrializationBinder and changing AssemblyName for Android namespace.